# pass list values to another page in JQuqery Mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, cordova

I have this script, which retrieves data from a `mysql` database and displays the results in a page in a `phonegap app` with `jquery mobile`. Now, what I want, is that if a user clicks on a result, then the user will be redirected to another page with the corresponding selected item in the list. What I mean is that selected item value will be passed into the new page (check page 6).

Here is the `php` script:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($num==0)
  echo "<br>Keine Datensätze gefunden";
  echo '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
  while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    echo '<li><div><h3>'
    .$dsatz["versicherungsnamen"] . "</h3>"
    .$dsatz["tarif-typ"] . "<p>Monatsprämie <b>CHF "
    .$dsatz["praemie"] . "</b></p><p><a href='#p6' data-icon='home' data-iconpos='top' data-transition='slide'>Offerte bestellen</a></p></div></li>";

  mysqli_close($con);
  echo '</ul>';

?>
```

The output will be generated in this div:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

If you need javascript, you can refer below, which passes the values from the form to the php script on to the server and return the results in `#output`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
      $("#krankenkasse").submit();
    });
    $("#krankenkasse").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#ajax-loader").css("display","block");
      $("#output").html("Loading Result...");
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://app.lovanet.ch/app/db_eingabe.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data, status){
          $("#ajax-loader").css("display","none");
          $("#output").html(data);
          // create mobile style listview
          $("#output").trigger("create");
        },
        error: function(){
          output.text('Keine Prämien gefunden.');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using standard URL parameters, so where you create the redirect edit the string to include parameters which uses the data you wish to pass.

```
/nextpage.html?nameofyourdata=youractualdata
```

Then on the receiving page just query the URL parameter using JavaScript, there are already a lot of questions about that on here!